# convert several images with ImageMagick in one command

Tags: image, unix, imagemagick

I would like to convert several images with imageMagick to rotated images (each one of them with a different direction: step = 10 degrees).
The command line to do that just for one image is as follow:

```
convert image.png -rotate 10 10-image.png
```

But how can I do it for several images?

PS: I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Your question is unclear... maybe show us the first three commands you want to run so we can work out the sequence you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can script this with `for` loop in a shell script, but I'm not entirely clear on one point of your question:

Does each rotation step have a different source image?  If so, a loop like this (`a*.png` represents the source images):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
r=0
for im in a*.png; do
    let "r=r+10"
    convert "$im" -rotate "$r" "$r-image.png"
done
```

If, on the other hand, there is a single source image of which you want to make several rotated versions, a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
r=0
while (( $r < 100 )); do
    let "r=r+10"
    convert image.png -rotate "$r" "$r-image.png"
done
```